# Passing ICollection<T> to database during migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hello I am trying to get the hang of MVC, and I'm trying to migrate a local website created with just angular to a .NET MVC app. From the json file I used for the website I am trying to create database models for the MVC app but I'm stuck at this error :

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'ConFusionMVC.Models.Comment'. Only primitive types or enumeration
>   types are supported in this context.

This is the sample json:

```
{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Zucchipakoda",
      "image": "images/zucchipakoda.png",
      "category": "appetizer",
      "label": "",
      "price": 1.99,
      "description": "dish description",
      "comments": [
        {
          "rating": 5,
          "comment": "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
          "author": "John Lemon",
          "date": "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
          "rating": 4,
          "comment": "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
          "author": "Paul McVites",
          "date": "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
          "rating": 3,
          "comment": "Eat it, just eat it!",
          "author": "Michael Jaikishan",
          "date": "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
      ]
    }
```

So the general idea is to have 2 model 'Dish' and 'Comments' with a 1:many relationship so Dish contains an ICollection of Comments. Theses are the classes

```
public class Dish
    {
        [Key]
        public int DishID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }

public class Comment
    {
        [Key]
        public int CommentID { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
    }
```

And my DbContext Class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DbSet<Dish> Dishes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }


        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Dish>()
                .HasMany(s => s.Comments);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }
```

I am using the code-first migrations approach, which is where I am having the error. This is my seed implementation:

```
var comments = new List<Comment>
            {
                new Comment { Rating = 5, Author = "John Lemon",
                    Comments = "author comments",
                    DatePosted = DateTime.Parse("2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z")
                },
                new Comment { Rating = 4, Author = "Paul McVites",
                    Comments = "author comments",
                    DatePosted = DateTime.Parse("2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z")
                },
                new Comment { Rating = 3, Author = "Michael Jaikishan",
                    Comments = "Eat it, just eat it!", DatePosted = DateTime.Parse("2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z")
                },

            };

            comments.ForEach(p => context.Comments.AddOrUpdate(c => c.CommentID, p));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var dishes = new List<Dish>
            {

                new Dish
                {
                    Name ="Uthapizza", Image="~/Images/uthapizza.png", Category="Mains",
                    Label ="Hot", Price=4.99, Description="dish comments" ,
                    Comments = new List<Comment>()
                    {
                        comments[0],comments[1], comments[2]
                    }
                },
                new Dish
                {
                    Name="Zucchipakoda", Image="~/Images/zucchipakoda.png",
                    Category="Appetizer", Label="Hot", Price=1.99, Description = "dish comments",
                    Comments = new List<Comment>()
                    {
                        comments[0],comments[1], comments[2]
                    }
                },

            };

            dishes.ForEach(s => context.Dishes.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Comments, s));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

How do I get the comments to be saved to the database for each individual dish? Please Assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as shown below.

```
  new Dish
      {
        Name ="Uthapizza", Image="~/Images/uthapizza.png", Category="Mains",
        Label ="Hot", Price=4.99, Description="dish comments" ,
        Comments = new List<Comment>()
               {
                 new Comment { Rating = 5, Author = "John Lemon",
                              Comments = "author comments",
                              DatePosted = DateTime.Parse("2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z")
                },
                new Comment { Rating = 4, Author = "Paul McVites",
                             Comments = "author comments",
                             DatePosted = DateTime.Parse("2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z")
                },
                new Comment { Rating = 3, Author = "Michael Jaikishan",
                             Comments = "Eat it, just eat it!",   DatePosted = DateTime.Parse("2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z")
                 },

              }
         },
```

Comment: Nah its still the same error but this time it gives an error location. It was on the last addorupdate

Comment: It was compile time. Its working now, I was updating by comments instead of ID. Why didn't the method I tried not work anyway?

Comment: OK good.you cannot add `list items` like that.you have to follow above procedure to do that.please read this : https://www.dotnetperls.com/list

Comment: you can `up vote` too :) please see how to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/tour